# Can you do a spatial join of multiple point layers with just 1 polygon layer as the target?

Tags: overlay, polygon, point, arcmap

I have multiple layers of point features all for the same province. I want to do a spatial join to then classify certain areas (polygon layer) based on the total number of points, from all point layers, inside the polygons. Is there a way to do that, because on the spatial join wizard it only allows 1 feature layer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [merge](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) tool to combine all of your point layers into a single layer with all of your points, then run your desired spatial join using that single layer.